# multiple equations in a single line, numbering problem

Tags: numbering

I have two relatively short equations which I want to fit in one line. Using the multicols and miniage I am getting :

equation1, (1)  equation2.  (2)

The numbers are on the right side of each equations but I want something like that:

equation1,  equation2   (1),(2)

Where the both numbers are together on the far right. I've just spent the last hour looking for the answer and still no idea.

Comment: Wouldn't that be confusing?

Comment: It's a strange usage.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? What about [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ovr4m.png)?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Two equation numbers within one set of brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100607/5764)

Answer (score 1):

This is about as simple as it gets.  The rule is used to provide context.  Also, for some reason it doesn't like \stepcounter{equation}, so I had to do it old school.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stepeq}{\global\advance\c@equation by 1}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}\stepeq{),(}\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
x&=a & y&=b
\end{align}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
z=c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: equations]

Comment: This doesn't really work, since references don't function as expected.

Comment: Even using \tag, you can't create separate references for the two equations using \label and \ref.  But it's not like we were encouraging this sort of thing.