# How can I number the different equations in one line?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write the different but similar equations in one line, just like the picture shows, I know maybe the `\tag` command can work, but I have no idea on how to make the numbering automatic.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173881/multiple-equations-in-a-single-line-numbering-problem/174089?s=2|0.5972#174089

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how rich your original code are, however with the following minimal example, you can generate the equation numbers as required.

**Note:**  Here, I have defined and used `\seteqn{<no. of eqn numbers>}` and `\reseteqn`.

**`\seteqn{2}`** This command will print two equation numbers, and likewise if you want `4` equation numbers, then `\seteqn{4}` will do the job.  This may be given just above the equation.

**`\reseteqn`** This may be used to reset the equation number format to the default.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\seteqn[1]{%
  \global\let\savetheEqn\theequation%
  \edef\@tempz{#1}%
  \def\@EqnNum{}%
  \edef\@currEqnCtr{\value{equation}}%
  \loop\ifnum\@tempz>0\relax%
    \xdef\@currEqnCtr{\number\numexpr\@currEqnCtr+1}%
    \xdef\@EqnNum{\ifx\@EqnNum\@empty\else\@EqnNum,\fi\@currEqnCtr}%
    \edef\@tempz{\number\numexpr\@tempz-1}%
  \repeat%
  \def\theequation{\@EqnNum}
}
\newcommand\reseteqn{\setcounter{equation}{\@currEqnCtr}%
  \global\let\theequation\savetheEqn}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn1}
eqn:1
\end{equation}

\seteqn{2}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn2,3}
eqn:2,3
\end{equation}
\reseteqn

\begin{equation}\label{eqn4}
eqn:4
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :)  it works but I'm just a new man in using LaTeX, maybe I should pay some time to learn the code you provided