# How we can write two equation together with equation number in same bracket?

Tags: equations

Following is the equation I want to write in latex in the same way:

^2+^2=^2          ^(−)            (3,4)

Comment: Do you mean you want 2 different equation numbers in the same bracket or just one overall equation number?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I just realized that if I understood your question correctly, then your question and my answer might be duplicates of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100611/121799) and [@percusse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100611/121799). (I should maybe say that I did not know of this when writing my answer, but yes, I *should* have checked.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 c=d
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2\quad\text{and}\quad\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\omega t}
\tag{\stepcounter{equation}\theequation,\stepcounter{equation}\theequation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 h=k
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe not needed, but (since it's really bad form to string separate `equation`s one after another) this works equally well with `gather`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I fully agree with that. We had this already at other occasions. I just try to give the user what she's asking for. and I am of course aware of [this discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7711/what-i-really-really-love). And I do agree that gather may look better (but still not good enough that I would use it myself, I'd prefer simply to have two separate lines. ;-) But thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[preview,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a\times b = c \quad\text{and}\quad a + b = d
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Extra services

If you need inter text without leaving the displayed equation environment, use `\intertext` as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence before my important formulae.
\begin{gather}
a\times b = c \qquad\text{and}\qquad a + b = d\\
\intertext{I can also show another sentence without leaving the gather environment. Is it cool, right?}
E= m c^\text{two}
\end{gather}
A sentence after the gather environment.
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Notes

I use `standalone` document class instead of `article` just for making the attached images more compact. Replace it with any document class that suits your best.